# R: How to run between group t-tests?

Tags: r, statistics

I am attempting to run a series of t-tests in R when splitting groups in the same dataset. I have easily been able to group data using `group_by` and selecting necessary variables. I also understand how to easily run t-tests using the `t.test` functions but these do not solve the problem of groups.

The data set consists of a group of participants completing an intervention with two different conditions, and varying degrees of load (see below for example).

```
Participant Condition   Load    var.1   var.2   var.3
P01         a           1       834.99  0.383   0.342
P01         a           2       917.22  0.342   0.301
P01         a           3       995.24  0.305   0.263
P01         b           1       1074.22 0.276   0.235
P01         b           2       1156.46 0.247   0.208
P01         b           3       871.41  0.307   0.277
P02         a           1       945.10  0.290   0.260
P02         a           2       1010.39 0.272   0.239
P02         a           3       1096.92 0.265   0.234
P02         b           1       1171.91 0.227   0.195
P02         b           2       664.00  0.260   0.191
P02         b           3       711.92  0.238   0.175
P03         a           1       782.02  0.211   0.154
P03         a           2       858.70  0.174   0.134
P03         a           3       915.21  0.154   0.114
P03         b           1       668.22  0.178   0.207
P03         b           2       723.92  0.243   0.186
P03         b           3       788.31  0.209   0.157
```

I have split groups using:

```
    grouped.my.df <- my.df %>%
      group_by(Condition, Load) %>%
      select(-var.4, -var.5,-var.6)
```

I have then tried to run t-tests but not sure how to run it from groups created within the `tbl`. Is it better to create vectors of each group (if so how) or can I run t-tests directly with the groups created? (The below code is an example of what I want to do, I know it doesn't actually function).

```
t.test(group.P01.a.1$var.1, group.P01.b.1$var1)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are not applying `group_by` correctly. It doesn't really do anything the way you use it right now.

You can select a subset of your data set with `filter`, e.g.:

```
grouped.a.1 = my.df %>% filter(Condition == "a", Load == 1)
grouped.b.1 = my.df %>% filter(Condition == "b", Load == 1)
```

and then use that in the `t.test`:

```
t.test(grouped.a.1$var.1, grouped.b.1$var.1)
```

or, because `t.test` also accepts a formula argument if there are two groups:

```
t.test(var.1 ~ Condition, my.df %>% filter(Load == 1))
```

Both test the `a` condition against the `b` condition for `Load == 1`. I assume that the discrimination by participant in your `t.test(group.P01.a.1$var.1, group.P01.b.1$var1)` line was unintended.

I think I misunderstood your question, and what you want may be something like

```
my.df %>%
    select(-Participant) %>%
    group_by(Load) %>%
    summarize_at(
        vars(-group_cols(), -Condition),
        list(p.value = ~ t.test(. ~ Condition)$p.value) )
```

This will give you the p-values of all two-group t-tests between the two conditions for all values of `Load` and all variables.

Comment: Yeah ok, I was wondering whether or not to create subsets of the data as some tutorials have said not to. I feel like if I'm doing things this way however, it may be just as easy to use SPSS. Trying to get my head further around R however so using this as a tutorial for myself. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: In my head, I thought it would be easy to `group_by` and create vectors from formed groups. Then it would be easy (but time consuming) to run a heap of t-tests, but, i read a few blog posts that said not to split the main df into subsets for whatever reason. I was then trying to figure out if I could run the tests without subsetting but I don't think it would be all that easy. So, yes I am pretty sure you understood the question.

Comment: This looks like it will be more exact in what I was thinking, as soon as I can get back to the screen, I will give you a definitive answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: Input the code and got: `Error in groups(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default`. Have gone back over it a couple of times to make sure what I input is the same as what you had written so not sure what I am doing incorrectly.